# Wait for permission in my application ? Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Did someone know a trick to wait for user read/write storage permission on Xamarin ?
I've been looking for that but didn't found a good solution without using plugin.

My application doesn't wait for the user permissionn, it mean that when my code is working on the device directories. VS is returning an Exception...

[image: EX]

My app is crashing when I am using this line of code :

```
string path = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path;

List<string> files1 = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
.Where(s => s.EndsWith(".pdf"))
.ToList();
```

I don't know if this thing happens only on emulator or also on real device.

Main activity :

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage) != (int)Permission.Granted)
        {
            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new string[] { Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage }, 0);
        }

        if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage) != (int)Permission.Granted)
        {
            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new string[] { Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage }, 0);
        }

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("CollectionView_Experimental");
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
```

I know this lines are not usefull :

```
if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage) != (int)Permission.Granted)
        {
            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new string[] { Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage }, 0);
        }

        if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage) != (int)Permission.Granted)
        {
            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new string[] { Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage }, 0);
        }
```

Any advice pls ?

Comment: do you have the external storage permission in your manifest?

Comment: Yes read and write permission, my app is asking for permission but when the permission are request this is already to late because my code is already asking for files in the device directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before performing that operation, ask for user permission, and allow that only if permission granted, otherwise display a user alert.

You can use `PermissionsPlugin` for the same, Which allows you to ask for the permission and give status if permission granted or denied.
Please refer this for more detail: [How to ask user for accessing permission in Xamarin.forms](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin)

Comment: Well, I tried on my real android device and it doesn't do the issue reported in this topic. That is very strange. I thing this problem only appear when I am running my app on an emulator to be honest